# Classic ASP Webserver On Windows 7

Tags: testing, asp-classic, webserver

I need to run some classic ASP locally before deployment to a legacy web application. To make things worse, my current workstation is a Windows 7 Ultimate x64 with VS2008 environment.

What are my options for testing/debugging?

One option I tried was [Baby ASP Server](http://www.pablosoftwaresolutions.com/html/baby_web_server.html), but I am actually running an ASP script I know should fail (on CreateObject()), does fail, but the error messages are extremely uninformative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What prevents you from installing IIS with support for ASP?

Go to Control Panel and then "Turn Windows features on and off"
[alt text http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/7204/windowsfeatures.png](http://img513.imageshack.us/img513/7204/windowsfeatures.png)

Comment: Ok, I feel pretty stupid now... I completely forgot to do that.

Comment: No worries, I won't tell anyone :)